# Parent class property set by parent method blank when accessing from child method

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, properties

I'm having trouble understanding why I can access a property from my parent class, but it's NULL, even though it has already been set by the parent (and has not been knowingly reset).  I thought it might be because that property was set by a private method, but no difference when I changed to public.  Here's a radically simplified example:

```
class TheParent
{

    protected $_parent_property;

    function __construct()
    {}

    private function parent_method($property);
    {
        $this->_parent_property = $property;
            $call = new TheChild;
            $call->child_method();
    }
}

class TheChild extends TheParent
{ 
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::construct();
    }

    public function child_method();
    {
        echo $this->_parent_property;
            exit;
    }
}

$test = new TheParent;
$test->parent_method('test');
```

I worked around this by passing the parent property to the child when the child is constructed by the parent ie `new TheChild($this->_parent_property)`, but I still don't understand why $this->_parent_property is set to NULL when accessed from the child in my original example.

**I do know that if I set this property from the parent constructor, I'd be able to access it just fine.  I'm trying to understand why a property set by a parent method, and accessible by other parent methods, is not accessible from the child class which extends the parent.**

Can anyone explain?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new instance where the variable isn't set. The property is bound to a particular instance, so you're creating one instance of the parent and then from the parent another instance of the child,i which includes all the stuff creating a new parent would contain, including `$_parent_property`. When you read the value in the child, you're reading the value of a newly created parent, not the one you previously created.

In effect, you do this:

```
A = new TheParent()
A->_parent_property = 'test'
```

Calls:
`B = new TheChild()` underneath the covers, this does `new TheParent()`

`Print B->_parent_property` (which was uninitialized)

Consider this similar example that will produce your expected result:

```
class TheParent
{

    protected $_parent_property;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent_method();
    }

    private function parent_method();
    {
        $this->_parent_property = 'test';
    }
}

class TheChild extends TheParent
{ 
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::construct();
    }

    public function child_method();
    {
        echo $this->_parent_property;
        exit;
    }
}

$child = new TheChild();
$child->child_method();
```

In this example, the private method in `TheParent` is invoked on the same instance created by `TheChild`, setting the underlying instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mark.  I just updated my example to show that I am passing the value for the parent property when the parent method is called.  Based on your answer, I suppose it's impossible to preserve that original param value in a property without first passing it to the child class?

Comment: @Calvin: your relationship is backwards, `TheChild` inherits from `TheParent`, if you want `TheChild` extend `TheParent` you should either expose the setter method to `TheChild`, or remove the inheritance relationship and pass an instance of `TheParent` to `TheChild` (or just the variable you need)

Comment: They're called static variables. And why is `TheParent` instantiating `TheChild`?

Comment: @todda: static variables are not the same as fields (sometimes called properties), and here the variable in question is a field, not a static field. In my example, `TheChild` instantiates `TheParent`, not the other way around, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Mark  I understand now.  I think removing the inheritance relationship and passing an instance of the parent class is definitely the way to go.  Thanks for your help, man = )

Comment: @todda The parent is instantiating the child because the children essentially exist as modules.  Each of the children (there are several of them) use helper functions from the parent.  Anyhow, based on what I learned from this thread I've changed that relationship slightly.

Answer (score 4):

You have a slightly wrong idea of how inheritance works.

`TheParent` is a class, and `TheChild` is a class based on the `TheParent`. `$test` now is an instance of `TheParent`. It has no idea that there is another class `TheChild` based on the class `TheParent`.

You create a new instance `$call` which is of type `TheChild`. This is, to use another word, a new object. It has nothing to do with `$test`, except that both are "compatible" to `TheParent`.

`TheChild` (`$call`) inherits the property `_parent_property` from its parent (class). However, that property is not initialised/set in that instance (object), so it is still `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, Mark's answer helped clarify that.  I upvoted you anyway for taking the time to read and reply.  Thanks = )